# Trying to get the files in my folder to reproject if the SR doesn't match the input SR

Tags: arcpy

Trying to get my local var's to pull the description from my Dataset_Folder which holds many datasets. It won't pull anything. I have tried "" and "*" to get something but nothing.

```
# Name: Re-Projection.py
# Description: Target Projection Dataset whose spatial reference will be used as specified projection in the re-projection
# Created by: Leah Cummins
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

class NoExist(Exception):#Create error class
    print "Error, script not working"
    pass

#Set the parameters
Dataset_Folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  #Get input folder dataset
Target_Projection_Dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # Get projection input folder
Projected_Dataset_Folder = ""  #target folder output re-projected dataset

#Set workspace
env.workspace = r"C:/Data"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outWorkspace = Projected_Dataset_Folder

for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*"):

    #Local Variables
    desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
    sr = desc.spatialReference
    projectedsr = arcpy.Describe(Target_Projection_Dataset)
    psr = projectedsr.spatialReference

    try:
        if sr.Name == psr.Name:  #SR are the same remain the same and copy to output folder
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Dataset_Folder,Projected_Dataset_Folder)
            print "added"

        else:
            arcpy.Project_management(Dataset_Folder, Projected_Dataset_Folder, psr.Name)

    except NoExist:
        print "error please try again"

    #Output Messages
    arcpy.AddMessage (outputfc +  ' with old projection: ' + fcsrName) #shape files and old spatial reference names
    arcpy.AddMessage (outfile) #add message of input that show that was copied and had the same spatial reference
    arcpy.AddMessage ("Completed Successfully")# Report a sucsess message
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [tour]. Please use the code block formatting tool (`{}`) on Python code. You also need to report what error you are getting.

Comment: What happens if you just use `for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():` without anything in the parentheses?  How do you know it's not pulling anything?  Have you added a `print infc` at the top of your `for` loop?  I'd remove the `try`/`except` from your code until you get it working.  That way you see all errors that might be occurring in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

- In the class `NoExist` definition you are printing; the print function will be executed at the start up time when defining the class.
- Variable `Target_Projection_Dataset` should not be a folder, it should be a dataset (shapefile or feature class, for instance). You cannot get a spatial reference information from a folder.
- Variable `Projected_Dataset_Folder` is empty yet you need to set it up to be a file folder where your datasets will be exported to.
- Since you are taking all the input datasets in the workspace, using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` without `*` is enough.
- I'd prefer comparing the projections on two datasets using the `factoryCode` property (aka wkid) instead of names; so use `sr.factoryCode == psr.factoryCode`.
- The Copy Features GP tool needs input dataset path and output dataset path; you have been supplying two folders. You should be calling `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(infc, os.path.join(Projected_Dataset_Folder, infc))` instead.
- Same with the Project GP tool; call `arcpy.Project_management(infc, os.path.join(Projected_Dataset_Folder, infc), psr)`. Keep in mind that the tool expects to get for the `out_coor_system` parameter `a Spatial Reference object, a file with a .prj extension, or a string representation of a coordinate system`. Since you already have a `Spatial Reference` object (obtained from the `Describe` object, you can use this one.
- You don't use the variable `outWorkspace`; this can be removed.

The whole code with minimal changes just to make it work right. If you expose your script as a toolbox custom script, you need of course to remove the hard-coded paths I've specified for input parameters:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

class NoExist(Exception):#Create error class
    print "Error, script not working"
    pass

#Set the parameters
Dataset_Folder = r'C:\GIS\Datasets' #arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  #Get input folder dataset
Target_Projection_Dataset = r'C:\GIS\Datasets\counties.shp'#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # Get projection input folder
Projected_Dataset_Folder = r'C:\GIS\Temp'  #target folder output re-projected dataset

#Set workspace
env.workspace = Dataset_Folder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    #Local Variables
    desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)
    sr = desc.spatialReference
    projectedsr = arcpy.Describe(Target_Projection_Dataset)
    psr = projectedsr.spatialReference

    try:
        if sr.factoryCode == psr.factoryCode:  #SR are the same remain the same and copy to output folder
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(infc, os.path.join(Projected_Dataset_Folder, infc))
            print "added"

        else:
            arcpy.Project_management(infc, os.path.join(Projected_Dataset_Folder, infc), psr)

    except NoExist:
        print "error please try again"
```

The reviewed version of the code (made it cleaner and more Pythonic):

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

class NoExist(Exception):#Create error class
    pass

#Set the parameters
input_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  #Get input folder dataset
target_projection_dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # Get projection input folder
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  #target folder output re-projected dataset

#Set workspace
env.workspace = input_folder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    input_sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference
    target_sr = arcpy.Describe(target_projection_dataset).spatialReference
    out_fc = os.path.join(output_folder, fc)

    try:
        if input_sr.factoryCode == target_sr.factoryCode:  #SR are the same remain the same and copy to output folder
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, out_fc)
            print "copied {0} to {1}".format(fc, out_fc)

        else:
            arcpy.Project_management(fc, out_fc, target_sr)
            print "re-projected {0} to {1}".format(fc, out_fc)

    except NoExist:
        print "error please try again"
```